# PHP Constructor seems to be not called - properties remain empty

Tags: php, mysql, database, constructor

I'm on my way to learn oop php.

So currently i'm trying to code two classes which should handle my database setup.

one called `Dbh` (Dbh.class.php) where i store all the database information to build a connection - the other called `db-setup` (db-setup.class.php) which actually should set up all the tables needed later on.

**My Problem** the connection properties in the `Dbh` class  seem not to get initialized once i instantiate a new object from within the `db-setup` class, which extends from `Dbh`. When i try to access the properties via `var_dump()` they are all `null`. But when i instantiate a new object form the `Dbh`class they will be initialized correctly.

Here's my code so far:

```
(dbh.class.php)
<?php

class Dbh
{
    protected $host;
    protected $user;
    protected $pwd;
    protected $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $ini = parse_ini_file("../path);

        if ($ini['env'] == 'dev') {
            $this->host = 'foo';
            $this->user = 'foo';
            $this->pwd = 'foo';
            $this->name = $ini['db'];
        } elseif ($ini['env'] == 'live') {
            $this->host = '';
            $this->user = '';
            $this->pwd = '';
            $this->name = $ini['db'];
        } else die('check env-parameter');
    }

    public function connect()

    {
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->name, $this->user, $this->pwd);
            return $dbh;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die('Error - dbh.class.php: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>');
        }
    }

    public function getHost()
    {
        $foo = 'that's the Host: ' . $this->host;
        return $foo;
    }
}

---------------------------------

(db-setup.class.php)

<?php
include 'dbh.class.php';

class DbSetup extends Dbh
{

    protected $tbl_client;
    protected $tbl_user;
    protected $tbl_consultation;
    protected $tbl_solution;
    protected $tbl_ext_counseling_center;
    protected $tbl_ext_counsultant;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tbl_client = 'wbdb_client';
        $this->tbl_user = 'wbdb_user';
        $this->tbl_consultation = 'wbdb_consultation';
        $this->tbl_solution = 'wbdb_solution';
        $this->tbl_ext_counseling_center = 'wbdb_ext_counseling_center';
        $this->tbl_ext_counsultant = 'wbdb_ext_counsultant';
    }

    public function createUserTable()
    {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare('CREATE TABLE ' . $this->tbl_user . ' (

                uid INT(8) PRIMARY KEY  AUTO_INCREMENT,
                last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                date_of_birth DATE,street VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                house_number INT(8) NOT NULL,
                zip INT(8) NOT NULL,
                city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                phone VARCHAR(20),
                email VARCHAR(255),
                status VARCHAR(30))'); //volunteer or employed
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e;
        }

        try {
            $stmt->execute();
            echo 'table: ' . $this->tbl_user . ' successfully created';
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
    }
}

$setup1 = new DbSetup();
var_dump($setup1);
$setup2 = new Dbh();
var_dump($setup2);;
```

So the `var_dump` returns:

```
/var/www/html/classes/db-setup.class.php:127:
object(DbSetup)[1]
  protected 'host' => null
  protected 'user' => null
  protected 'pwd' => null
  protected 'name' => null
  protected 'tbl_client' => string 'wbdb_client' (length=11)
  protected 'tbl_user' => string 'wbdb_user' (length=9)
  protected 'tbl_consultation' => string 'wbdb_consultation' (length=17)
  protected 'tbl_solution' => string 'wbdb_solution' (length=13)
  protected 'tbl_ext_counseling_center' => string 'wbdb_ext_counseling_center' (length=26)
  protected 'tbl_ext_counsultant' => string 'wbdb_ext_counsultant' (length=20)

/var/www/html/classes/db-setup.class.php:129:
object(Dbh)[2]
  protected 'host' => string 'foo' (length=25)
  protected 'user' => string 'foo' (length=3)
  protected 'pwd' => string 'foo' (length=3)
  protected 'name' => string 'foo' (length=4)
```

Since i'm a beginner in terms of php and oop i would appreciate your help.

thx in advance

Comment: You have to call `parent::__construct()` in extending class. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice: `parse_ini_file("../path);` is missing a closing `"`, but that might just be a typo here

Comment: Yes it was, but thx anyways!